# ASP.NET MVC - Date and time string validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, data-annotations

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and the application user will be able to encode a date with time. I'm wondering if I should use the DateTime.TryParse function to determine if it is a valid date time string or if I should use a Regular Expression in my ViewModel.

In case of using a Regex, is there any existing Date and Time regex? Because I didn't find one in the dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss format.

EDIT : I've decided to use the TryParseExact and check if the encoded date and time is valid.

The dates entered are 15/10/2014 13:00 and 15/10/2014 15:00

Here's what I'm doing :

```
DateTime dtS;
DateTime dtE;
DateTimeFormatInfo fmt = (new CultureInfo("fr-FR")).DateTimeFormat;
bool validStart = DateTime.TryParseExact(svm.StartApp, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", fmt, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtS);
bool validEnd = DateTime.TryParseExact(svm.EndApp, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", fmt, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtE);

if (!validStart || !validEnd)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

My bool variables are getting the false value and I cannot see why. Any idea?

Comment: Can you use some form of date/time picker? That will be a lot better than a single text field which could be filled in in various different formats...

Comment: In my humble opinion TryParse is perfect solution (better than regex).

Comment: @pwas: The only downside being that it's only available on the server-side. It's often a good idea to have a regex on the client-side, and then (obviously) validate on the server side too.

Comment: Side note: you'll want HH rather than hh. And any regex which handles leap years correctly is going to be pretty nasty, I suspect.

Comment: I agree with @pwas. Regex are not suited for this at all as you have several constraints on the date (month cannont be >12, maximum days per month depends on month number, etc ...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried to used that but I need a date AND time picker which is a bit tricky to implement in my project context... So TryParse guys?

Comment: Yes, if you *have* got it as a single string, and you only want to validate server-side, then TryParse (or TryParseExact) is fine. You should consider what culture you want to use though... Personally I prefer TryParseExact, as it's easier to predict.

Comment: @JonSkeet - right, but I wouldn't recommend to use regex on the client side (like you mentioned - such a regex would be a tricky one). For JS validation I'd recommend birlliant moment.js: http://momentjs.com/. Validation looks like then: `moment('some date').isValid();` (see docs)

Comment: @pwas: Right, makes sense.

Comment: Guys if you could have a look on my EDIT, I've got a problem with the TryParseExact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was in trying to get **seconds**. You have not seconds in  your string.

Now is working:

```
DateTime dtS;
DateTime dtE;
bool validStart = DateTime.TryParseExact("15/10/2014 13:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dtS);
bool validEnd = DateTime.TryParseExact("15/10/2014 13:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dtE);
```